# Creating multiple modal windows with same styling but different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have 140 link items that essentially are going to do a modal window of a user profile for each link. I have created a div(the modal window) and styled it but the problem is that the elements on each user profile have to be different. So there is a div containing 3 images which are going to be different for everyone, a profile picture, a paragraph of text and social icons.

What would be the easiest way to make this work? Been looking for some information for couple of hours with no results.

Comment: What have you already tried? Any code you can share with us?

Comment: I have coded the whole directory and coded and styled the modal div but I don't know how I could make the user profile system. I found an thread here which had similar question and 'gibberish' replied an useful post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263756/show-a-modal-window-with-html-content?rq=1 and I need something like that but I have no experience with ajax nor databases so I was looking maybe someone can point me in the right direction on how to actually make it work.